# AWS EFS - How to test Burst Credits Balance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-efs

I have created a Cloudwatch alarm when our EFS burst credits balance goes low under a specific value.
I was wondering, how I can test that metric of EFS Burst credits balance?
Is there a tool? I dont get how I can reduce (significantly) the burst credits of my EFS
in order to test the alert.
Any suggestion/ explanation what I should do?

I just tried to add more files but, the burst credits still high.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have an idea on how to mock Burst credits balance, but another way to make sure the alert works and the monitor monitors the right resource and watches the right merics is to lower the threshold of the alert just for the test to see if it triggers an alert as expected.
Don't forget to return the threshold to the desired value afterwards :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure you have the metrics correct and just want to test what happens when the alarm is triggered, there is an AWS CLI (and SDK) CloudWatch method that can be used to test an alarm, called [set-alarm-state](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/cloudwatch/set-alarm-state.html)

You can call it from the CLI using the name of your alarm. You can also set the state back when you have confirmed the alarm does what you want.

```
aws cloudwatch set-alarm-state --alarm-name "myalarm" --state-value ALARM --state-reason "testing purposes"
```